# Should I wait for version 6.0 or can I install elementaryOs right now?

Tags: updates

The reason I am asking is I want to switch from Windows to elementaryOs on my laptop before I go on a trip and I want to know if I will be able to update elementary from 5.x to 6.0 when the full release comes out or should I wait with my install till the 6.0 is finished?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not supported to update Elementary OS between versions.

However, since it's Linux running under the hood there may be someone who releases an "update script" that accomplishes this in the future.